# How to get Father off the roof?

Tags: fallout-4

I need Father for the meeting in [Mankind Redefined](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mankind_-_Redefined), as well as [Underground Undercover](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Underground_Undercover).
Unfortunately, Father is standing on top of a building near Boston library precinct. I have tried killing him and pushing him to the exit but it doesn't work.
How can I get him off the roof?

Comment: What mission is this?

Comment: It is the mission for the minute men and another mission which both require father being at the meeting called (Mankind Redefined) and             ( Underground Undercover)  @Vemonus

Comment: `[refID].moveto player` - Moves npc with refID to player

Comment: [Hey (pa), get off the dang roof!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJFa7NY0_wU)

Answer (score 1):

The Institute mission "Mankind Redefined" The Underground Railroad "Underground Undercover" entail the Institute mission "Powering Up" to complete.

If you haven't been able to get Father to meet you at the Institute Reactor, you may have one of two problems.

1.) Make sure you've met all the mission requirements to progress. Sometimes it's easy to miss a step in nested missions.

2.) You are likely suffering a glitch where Father won't move from his station. Players who have reported this glitch has so far only fixed it by reverting to an earlier save, and I've not read of or been able to find any documentation regarding patch fixes but see it mainly confined to the PC version of the game .